# Easiest way to scan books?

Tags: scanner, scanning

What's the easiest tool to use to scan books? I find that using my scanner is difficult for books?

Answer (score 4):

If you can separate the pages from the book (i.e.: break the book) I will suggest you a Fujitsu [Scansnap S300](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YA1XVG) because It's a good product (stellar reviews) and can OCR your book making It a searchable PDF.

If you're brave enough you can [build a system yourself](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-High-Speed-Book-Scanner-from-Trash-and-Cheap-C/)

If you think there could be an e-book (you've not said which book you want to scan) copy of your textbook try to purchase It.

There are [incredible](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2009/12/diy-book-scanner/) [projects](http://www.diybookscanner.org/) deidcated on this subject and It's worth mentioning a company: [Atiz](http://www.atiz.com/)

[This kind of device](http://www.virtual-laser-keyboard.com/docupen/R700.asp), depending on the number of pages you want to scan, can come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

There are local agencies in large cities which have this service, daily.  I'm not sure if China, India, etc offer a similar service at competitive prices.
e
Generally, I don't scan.  Newspapers, periodicals, books ...

I use my smartphone and /or my compact digital camera.  Then read it on my smartphone, notebook or netbook.  If I really want hardcopy, I laser-print any pages.

For uploading into assignments, Omnipage (optical character recognition) in Window$$$$.  Linux has a few free OCR programs, which i've installed, but have not tested.

Greg Zeng, Retired (medical) IT Consultant, Australian Capital Territory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xcanex](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2p_Nt2WQE0).
Tt can scan 16pages in 5 mins.
Use at home.
It also can be used to scan card, documents.

Answer (score 0):

A scanner with a document feeder should do what you're looking for - try to keep it to 5-10 pages at a time and hope that the pages aren't wrinkly at the edge that goes into the feeder.

Answer (score 0):

There are also scanners such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005AHBGZ6) one that allow you to scan almost to the center so you can do it on an intact book without breaking the spine.  I haven't used it, though.